# How Android app with Java front-end and Rails 4 backend?

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails

This is what I will be developing: "Android app with Java front-end and Rails 4 backend"
I would like some pointers. An example app on github would be great!
I know I have to specify the POST requests in Rails to be either JSON or XML. In my assets folder do I put java or what? How does it work? Where do I start?

Comment: Start here http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: My friend is building the Java frontend I am only responsible for the backend with Rails. I just need to understand how to link them?

Comment: Are you still here? Please tell me if I can provide more help.

Comment: @Andreas Lyngstad Thanks for answer. I just haven't had time to look into it. When I do I am surely going to ask more questions! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the rails backend into a API.

There is a [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) github project that you should start with.

These railscasts should help you along the way.

[348-the-rails-api-gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem)

[350-rest-api-versioning](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning)

[414-batch-api-requests](http://railscasts.com/episodes/414-batch-api-requests)

[352-securing-an-api](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api)